# Do Node.js API functions execute in separate threads

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

Javascript is single threaded. So every piece of code which I write is executed in a single thread of javascript runtime provided by Node. So when I execute following code:

```
var fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile('input.txt', function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
       return console.error(err);
   }
   console.log("Asynchronous read: " + data.toString());
});

// Synchronous read
var data = fs.readFileSync('input.txt');
```

Following is my understanding of workflow, please correct me if I am wrong:

`fs.readFile` is popped off the call stack by **manager** in Node immediately and moved to some other thread where it starts the reading stuff.

When reading is complete, **manager** in Node:

- puts the callback function of `fs.readFile` in the queue stack
- which event loop eventually puts in the call stack and executes

`fs.readFileSync` is not popped off the stack but is executed in the runtime thread itself like any other function.

So, who is this  **manager** in node which executes Node API I/O functions in other threads and manages their call stacks.

So does Node use multi-cores to execute it's API functions in the background?

Comment: There's no need for separate threads. The underlying operating system essentially functions as the "other" thread, and signals the Node process when I/O operations progress/complete.

Comment: @Pointy what pops fs.readFile from the call stack so that other functions can execute, is their a separate call stack for Node API functions where they are executed?

Comment: Nothing "pops" it from the call stack other than the fact that it simply returns immediately after initiating the I/O operation. (It uses an operating system asynchronous I/O call to do its work.)

Comment: @Pointy It makes sense, but what puts its callback in to the queue stack, and what about SetTimeOut()

Comment: The Node runtime manages callbacks etc. At the heart of it is a (probably fairly involved) loop that uses OS polling facilities, timers, etc. When something happens at a low level, the runtime has to map that to some piece of user code and invoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NodeJS is using event loop for asynchronous operations.

If you know, there is a library exists called **libuv**. libuv is responsible for asynchronous code execution. Here is a little pseudo-code how it managing this:

```
while there are still events to process:
  e = get the next event
  if there is a callback associated with e:
    call the callback
```

You can read more about libuv here - http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/introduction.html

So, basically:

> Do Node.js API functions execute in separate threads?

Both, yes and no. If function can move I/O operation to separate thread in thread-pool then yes. Otherwise it executes in the same thread.

> So, who is this manager in node which executes Node API I/O functions in other threads and manages their call stacks?

libuv - https://github.com/libuv/libuv

> So does Node use multi-cores to execute it's API functions in the background?

I don't know for sure, anyone can correct me if I'm wrong, but Node is executes within single-core. If you want to run with multi-core support, you need run it in cluster-mode.

UPD: Here is a little diagram that can help you to understand.
[image: How does NodeJS work]

Comment: It's a nice answer. In cluster mode, node actually works by creating multiple processes to use multiple cores - not threads.

Comment: Yeah, so if you want to run NodeJS in threads (not processes) you can take a look at fork of NodeJS - JXCore - http://jxcore.com/home/. JXCore exposes API for running your functions in separate threads and implements messaging between them.

Answer (score 0):

While looking for resources to quote on answering this I couldn't actually find any that go into much detail. There's a nice intro [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/) and some details on how the event loop works on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

It seems that there is another thread internal to the V8 engine which manages the event loop. This will take responses from things like operating system I/O and add the data and relevant callback to the queue. Every time the event loop finishes what it's doing it picks the next thing from the queue.